# use quotation marks as text in expression birt

Tags: expression, birt

I need to concatenate a value with a text. For that I have set-up a report variable that holds the text and I am trying to concatenate this with the database value. However the text contains quotation marks. My question is how to define the text so that the quotation marks are also printed as text. The text I need to print as text is

```
[advanced_iframe securitykey="f8928c314kjkhjkhkjhkhgf09213bf21d13a2" src="
```

I have tried this

```
"[advanced_iframe securitykey="f8928c314kjkhjkhkjhkhgf09213bf21d13a2" src=""
```

but this does not work.

Any help would be appreciated..

regards,

Michel

Comment: placing them between single quotes did the trick '"'

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes to define your text:

```
'[advanced_iframe securitykey="f8928c314kjkhjkhkjhkhgf09213bf21d13a2" src="'
```

or you have to escape each `"` inside the text with a forward slash `\` like this:

```
"[advanced_iframe securitykey=\"f8928c314kjkhjkhkjhkhgf09213bf21d13a2\" src=\""
```